# Python: Turn large text files into dataframe using format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, append

Making a web scraper to make list e.g. playlist info from spotify, job description from Indeed or company lists from Linked In. I now have large text files that I'd like to format into dataframes by turning into csv or dictionaries.

Text file:

```
Scribd
MobileQAEngineer




VitaminT
MobileQAEngineer




Welocalize
MobileQAEngineer




RWSMoravia
MobileQAEngineer
```

Desired output:

```
Scribd,MobileQAEngineer
VitaminT,MobileQAEngineer
Welocalize,MobileQAEngineer
RWSMoravia,MobileQAEngineer
```

I though I could try something such as:

```
if line of text does not have 4 \n afterwards
    then it is the 1st tuple
if line of text has 4 \n afterwards
    then it is the 2st tuple
```

```
with open(input("Enter a file to read: "),'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        newline = line + ":"
        #f.write(newline)
        print(newline)
```

While trying to place a ':' at the end of the line, I ended up placing one before and after the line:

```
:
Scribd
:
MobileQAEngineer
:


:
VitaminT
:
MobileQAEngineer
:


:
Welocalize
:
MobileQAEngineer
:


:
RWSMoravia
:
MobileQAEngineer
:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse your data using `regex` and then convert it to `DataFrame`:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

m = re.findall('(\w+)\n(\w+)', data)
d = {'Company': [c[0] for c in m], 'Position': [c[1] for c in m]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Output:

```
      Company          Position
0      Scribd  MobileQAEngineer
1    VitaminT  MobileQAEngineer
2  Welocalize  MobileQAEngineer
3  RWSMoravia  MobileQAEngineer
```

Comment: Hi Alderven, thank you. This worked! A big section of my file is formated different, how would I go about parsing that too?

Comment: "there is a difference in how the line breaks are distributed. i.e ``` Points International (linebreak) QAAnalyst (linebreak) (linebreak) (linebreak) GssAmericaInc (linebreak) ManualTester (linebreak) (linebreak) (linebreak) ElectronicArts (linebreak) MobileTester (linebreak) (linebreak) (linebreak)```

Comment: Thanks again, @Alderven . How can I find more information to fully understand this? `d = {'Company': [c[0] for c in m], 'Position': [c[1] for c in m]}`

Comment: Check [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for `[c[0] for c in m]` and `[c[1] for c in m]`